# Nullifying css padding

Tags: html, css

Seems like an odd question, but I seem to be at a loss. I have a menu where a user can choose how much space between the elements on the page. To do this I am using a list of different sizes of padding. Like so..

```
"Padding" : {
    "extendsValue" : "Css",
    "value" : "padding",
    "inputType" : "select",
    "selectOptions" : [
      { "value" : "auto", "display" : "0px" },
      { "value" : "10px", "display" : "10px" },
      { "value" : "20px", "display" : "20px" },
      { "value" : "30px", "display" : "30px" },
      { "value" : "40px", "display" : "40px" },
      { "value" : "50px", "display" : "50px" },
      { "value" : "60px", "display" : "60px" },
      { "value" : "70px", "display" : "70px" },
      { "value" : "80px", "display" : "80px" },
      { "value" : "90px", "display" : "90px" },
      { "value" : "100px", "display" : "100px" },
      { "value" : "150px", "display" : "150px" },
      { "value" : "200px", "display" : "200px" },
      { "value" : "250px", "display" : "250px" },
      { "value" : "300px", "display" : "300px" },
      { "value" : "350px", "display" : "350px" },
      { "value" : "400px", "display" : "400px" },
      { "value" : "450px", "display" : "450px" },
      { "value" : "500px", "display" : "500px" }
    ],
}
```

My issue seems to be when they select 0px even though I have it set to auto it is still setting the padding to 0. Which is causing issues with centering. Ideally when they select the 0 I would like the inline padding to just go away and take on the styling I already have in place.

Is there any way to do this? I've already tried null or just leaving it blank, but it always just wants to set it back at 0. **I do not want my padding to be 0.**

Comment: Please post your JavaScript code of how the CSS is set.

Comment: I agree with @Xufox, it depends on how you have implemented the logic

Comment: The css is set through knockout bindings and is actually really complex, but working fine. It literately takes the value though and throws it into a padding inline styling.

Comment: What about padding:inherit https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/padding#Syntax

Comment: But this will depend on padding set on parent elements (if any).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how you are using the dropdown but here's an idea.

Instead of doing `style = "padding:[value]"` you could just do the whole `style = [value]` like this:

```
"selectOptions" : [
  { "value" : "padding: 0px", "display" : "0px" },
  { "value" : "padding: 10px", "display" : "10px" },
  { "value" : "padding: 20px", "display" : "20px" },
  { "value" : "padding: 30px", "display" : "30px" },...
```

That was you can even add exceptions for additional styling if need be such as:

```
 "selectOptions" : [
      { "value" : "padding: 0px; display: inline", "display" : "0px" },
      { "value" : "padding: 10px", "display" : "10px" },
      { "value" : "padding: 20px", "display" : "20px" },
      { "value" : "padding: 30px", "display" : "30px" },...
```

Comment: I guess I should have posted my entire json object. This actually won't work because of that. It has to extend a value from the database which is the padding. and If I write it like this then it will be setting padding: padding: 10px.